# Let $f:ℝ\to ℝ^{+}$ be a decreasing function, wherein $f(0)$, $f(1)$ etc. are in GP. Find the interval in which $\int_0^{10}f(x)dx$ lies

Tags: integration

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{+}$ be a continuous decreasing function, wherein $f(0)$,$f(1)$ etc. are in GP with common ratio $\frac{1}{5}$. Find the interval in which $\int_0^{10}f(x)dx$ lies.

[image]

So I started by finding a relationship between $f(0)$ and $f(10)$ which is $f(10)=f(0)\frac{1}{5^{10}}$

and $f(0)> f(x)>f(10)$ (as the function is decreasing) where $x$ lies between $0$ and $10$.

or the integral lies between

$0$ and $f(10)$.

I was also thinking of estimating it using the GP summation, but I doubt that will help.

which makes no sense

Can I have a hint

Source :- IAT 2023

Edit 1, using the hints provided by Anne

$$f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)+f\left(2\right)+\ldots+f\left(10\right)<\int_0^{10}f\left(x\right)<f\left(1\right)+f\left(2\right)+f\left(3\right)+\ldots+f\left(10\right)$$

or

$$\frac{5f\left(0\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{11}-1\right)}{4}<\int_0^{10}f\left(x\right)<\frac{f\left(0\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{10}-1\right)}{4}$$

Edit 2:- An elucidation of my working and correction of mistakes

$$f\left(0\right)>\int_0^1f\left(x\right)>f\left(1\right)$$

$$f\left(1\right)>\int_1^2f\left(x\right)>f\left(2\right)$$

and so on until

$$f\left(9\right)>\int_9^{10}f\left(x\right)>f\left(10\right)$$

adding them up
$$\sum_{i=0}^9f\left(i\right)>\int_0^{10}f\left(x\right)dx>\sum_{i=0}^{10}f\left(i\right)$$

or

$$\frac{5f\left(0\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{10}-1\right)}{4}>\int_0^{10}f\left(x\right)>\frac{5f\left(1\right)\left(\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{10}-1\right)}{4}$$

Comment: Hint1: for $k=0,1,\dots,9$, $\int_k^{k+1}f(x)dx$ lies between $f(k)$ and $f(k+1)$. Hint2: $f(k)=f(0)/5^k$.

Comment: You did several mistakes in your edit1

Comment: Hint3: $$f\left(1\right)+f\left(2\right)+\dots+f\left(10\right)<\int_0^{10}f<f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)+\dots+f\left(9\right)$$

Comment: Hint3: $$\color{red}{f\left(1\right)}+f\left(2\right)+\dots+f\left(10\right)<\int_0^{10}f<f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)+\dots+f\left(9\right)$$

Comment: Hint4: $$\sum_{i=0}^9f\left(i\right)=\frac{5f\left(0\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{10}\right)}{4}$$

Comment: In your solution attempt at the bottom, the left (lesser) sum should be from $f(1)$ to $f(10)$, and the right (greater) sum should be from $f(0)$ to $f(9)$. This changes your later calculations as well.

Comment: Indeed Paul, and this is why repeated my "Hint3" with some red colour on the main point. Moreover, the OP's mistake is obvious since $f(0)+\dots+f(10)>f(0)+\dots+f(9)$. But anyway, Hint5: that lower bound is useless. $0<\int_0^{10}f$ is sufficient for our purposes.